# Draw a design with characters

Tags: c, character

Hi all I am a novice programmer and I study C and while studying yesterday I came across this exercise, here goes:

I have to create a  program which will take three parameters (c, n, m)
and it will paint a house. The first parameter (c) establishes the character with
which will form the house, while the second (n) and the third (m) determines the height
of the triangle (roof) and the rectangle of the house. For the creation of the roof the
program will  prints per line 1, 3 to (2 * n +1) characters. While then
it will display a ((2n-1) * m) rectangle. 
 for example: if you give as parameters: O,3,4 it will print

```
                    o
                   ooo
                  ooooo
                 ooooooo
                  ooooo
                  ooooo
                  ooooo
                  ooooo
```

So I decided to solve it but I am over 3 hours on this exercise and I just cant find the right conditions to put in the "for"  to create the roof I am okay with the rectangle so can someone give a helping hand with the roof please;

Comment: My tip is to make two loops per line of output: One for the leading spaces and one for the letters.

Answer (score 1):

May not be the best possible solution but here's a way to do it

```
void print_house(int c, int n, int m){
    int line_width;
    int max_width = 2*n +1;
    int padding = 0;
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;

    //print the roof
    for(i=0; i<= n; i++){
        line_width = 2*i +1;
        padding = (max_width - line_width)/2;

        for(k=0; k<padding; k++){
        printf(" ");
        }

        for(j=0; j< line_width; j++){
            printf("%c",c);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //print the rectangle
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        printf(" ");
        for(j=0;j< max_width -2; j++){
            printf("%c",c);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful. I haven't thought to use three loops.I was trying to solve it with 2 but with no good results.